# iOS4.2: TouchBegan does not draw more than one circle per sensed touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, touch, multi-touch

quick question (which might be a no-brainer for most here) :)

My code below should draw a circle for every time touch that is recognised but although more than ones touches are sensed only one circle will drawn up at a time.

**Can anyone see any obvious issues?**

This method sits in the `XYZViewControler.m` class.
`TouchPoint.m` is the class that defines the circle.

Thanks a bundle for your help and redirects.

Chris

---

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {

 NSSet * allTouches = [event allTouches];  // get all events

 for (UITouch * touch in touches) {

  TouchPoint * touchPoint = [[TouchPoint alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, circleWidth, circleWidth)];

  touchPoint.center = [touch locationInView:[self view]]; 
  touchPoint.color = [UIColor redColor];
  touchPoint.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  [[self view] addSubview: touchPoint];
  [touchPoint release];

  CFDictionarySetValue(touchMap, touch , touchPoint); 
 }

 [[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code if fine! One has to enable multitouch for the view in order to make it work!

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isMultipleTouchEnabled) BOOL multipleTouchEnabled
```